# Pendulum collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

this is my first request here!

I try to simulate collisions between a $N$-pendulum and free balls.
My $N$-pendulum is described by $\theta_i$, $\omega_i$, $m_i$ and $l_i$.

Free balls are described by their position, mass and speed.
I have equation for my $N$-pendulum (found with Lagrange formalism) and I also have equation for elastic collision between two free balls.

However, I don't know how to deal with collision that occurs between a pendulum's ball ($ball_i$) and a free ball. I think this collision must change all $\omega_j$ but I don't know how to deal with cases $i\ne j$.

I heard about Lagrange multipliers that maybe can help me if I add external force but I don't know how to do it properly.

I'm a student in computer science and since I'm not confident with dynamics, I really need your help..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mass points never meet in dimension greater 1.  Your problem even in dimension 1 has produced tons of paper during the last 100 years, because, simply said, more than two particles produce a space of momentums and positions, that is not describable by equations, but by a ladder of case distinctions.

Beginning with dimension 2, the mass points either need a repulsive potential for establishing a conservative Lagrangian, or a hard core with a law of momentum conservation in their respective pair-center-of-gravity system.

This, immediately again, involves case distinctions and - additionally - uncontrollable 3-body collisions at exact equal time, a problem that has no solution. But the set of starting values that produce 3-collisions,  has measure zero and so never occurs in simulations.

Unfortunately, too, short time discretization approximations of n-particle mechanics generate garbage instead viable physical models. As somebody countered Laplace with his idea of everyting to be fixed for all times by the initial condition: yes, series expansion converges in a complex circle of  about 10^-{44} s for a system of 10 particles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case, I deal only with 2D modelling and I use Runge Kutta in my simulation so obviouly, result can't be physically perfect. However, I've seen a youtube video where someone manages to simulate this, with a double pendulum. My goal, basically, is not to produce a super physically accurate simulation. In my case, when I only change $\omega_i$ where collision occurs here, this change of angular speed only at $i$, is not efficient enough, so I got balls that go through each others.
This what I really want to avoid.

Comment: If there is a way to change all $\omega_j$ so that my collision only changes initial conditions for my solver, that would be perfect.